# Poll Interval for Kafka Connect SourceTask

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm implementing a custom Source Connector using the Kafka-Connect API, that can be used to poll REST-APIs and sink the JSON response into a Kafka topic.

Now I'm wondering how to realize a polling interval for the SourceTask, how the JDBC Connector offers one. Somewhere I have to set the thread to sleep, but where do I have to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this use case in my `SourceTask` implementation by adding a private field of type `long` to store a time stamp. At the first `poll()` invocation the field is not yet initialized, therefore the configured REST-APIs get polled. While this first invocation the mentioned `long` field get's initialized with the current time stamp. In all following `poll()` invocations this time stamp of the previous invocation get's checked. If the amount of elapsed milliseconds since the previous `poll()` is smaller than the configured interval between two polls, I send the thread to sleep since the configured milliseconds are elapsed.

Answer (score -2):

Use `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Please refer to this link: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Comment: That's not exactly what i'm looking for. The _max.poll.interval.ms_ defines the max gap between _poll_ invocations, before a consumer will leave the group, e.g. if a thread is blocked. It works like a timeout. But I'm looking for a solution to control how often the _poll_ method will get called. By default it's continuously, i'm looking for a solution to call _poll_ from a connector thread e.g. every five minutes.

Comment: This property is for consumer, the question is about Kafka Connect Source Connector.